# KDB count unique combination of columns

Tags: kdb

assuming I have a table like

```
tbl:flip `id`evt!(1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3; `a`b`c`a`b`b`b`c`a`c)
```

How can I efficiently count the occurrences of evt but only once per id

So, the result should look like this (or any other format that maps evt to the unique count)

```
res:flip `evt`ct !(`a`b`c; 3 2 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be something like this:

```
q)select count distinct id by evt from tbl
evt| id
---| --
a  | 3
b  | 2
c  | 3
```

If you want it unkeyed like in your sample, you can add `0!` to the start

Comment: that was quick. and simpler than I expected. I like simple. thanks a lot

Comment: I will. you were just too quick. Need to wait a few more minutes before it will allow me to accept an answer

Comment: Ah apologies, didn't realise you had to wait a certain period!

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to the above approach but you can also run `distinct` on the entire table before counting the occurences of `id`:

```
q)select count id by evt from distinct tbl
evt| id
---| --
a  | 3
b  | 2
c  | 3
```